# Require a form to be filled out to download a .pdf?

Tags: php, html

Can I dynamically make a page with download links for PDF files and require user fill out HTML form before able to download the .PDF files?

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished all in html or with PHP and HTML.  But, I like the PHP implementation better because it allows for more secure input verification and it allows for more backward and browser compatibility.  The JavaScript method would require data urls, which aren't supported in certain web browsers.

```
<?php

  function startDownload($filePath) {
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename(urlencode($filePath)));   
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");  
    $fp = fopen($filePath, "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
      echo fread($fp, 65536);
      flush();
    } 
    fclose($fp);
    die();      
  }

  //Note that I decided to check specifically for the strings and didn't just take the hidden field here
  //  If we just assume the user isn't a liar, 

  if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['file'])) {
    if ($_POST['file'] == "pdfurl-guide.pdf") {
      startDownload("pdfurl-guide.pdf");
    } else if ($_POST['file'] == "someOther.pdf") {
      startDownload("someOther.pdf");
    } else {
      echo "error";
    }
  }

?>

Please fill out the following form to download:
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="file" value="pdfurl-guide.pdf" /> 
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<br />
What if you want this file?    
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="file" value="someOther.pdf" /> 
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The page I am referring to is: http://www.workrite.com/fr-information/downloads/tech-briefs-white-sheets_new.php

Any way to have multiple buttons with the same form?

Comment: @BillyFischbach  I think this is what you meant.  I added functionality for multiple downloads.  If you simply want more than one button that does the same thing, you can add more than one `<input type="submit" />` or submit via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There are many ways. You could simply hide the download button using jQuery until the form has been submited and show it after.

Or if the person enters their email send them an email containing a URL with a unique string that you generate (E.g. www.yourwebsite.com/pdf.php?s=h4jbsj5623v6) and also save this string to your database.

Than create a PHP file that generates a pdf document using [TCPDF library](https://tcpdf.org/) or any other similar PHP library that is capable of generating a .pdf file.

When the person visits the download URL check in your database if their unique string, that is passed as a GET parameter exists. And if it does display them the pdf document using previously mentioned library.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I am trying to make this work using a single html form with multiple .pdf files. Do you think I can make it work with php, jquery?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with multiple .pdf files... The user can check which PDF's they want to download?

Comment: I have multiple buttons one page that have download links:http://www.workrite.com/fr-information/downloads/tech-briefs-white-sheets_new.php

Comment: Again you have many ways to solve this... You could add a hidden field to the form. And than add onclick event to every download button `onClick="$('#hidden').val('myFile.pdf')"`.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ekgko1t/)

And after the person submits the form get the file name from $_POST parameters and redirect them to it.

Comment: Thank you. I am gonna try that and give it a shot !